# Install IPA using itms-services from disk on iOS device

Tags: ios, security, distribution

Is it possible to install an iOS IPA from disk?

All of the examples I've seen involve using itms-services to install from a URL off the internet like so:

```
NSString* pListUrl = @"itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=<url to my plist file>"
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:plistUrl]];
```

The problem here is that the request via openURL by the system to grab the ipa I suppose assumes that no credentials will be necessary to access it.  I would like to retrieve the IPA securely via my secure socket, and then tell iOS to install from a local file or even NSData.

Any thoughts on how to secure my ipa would be appreciated.

Comment: Please see this topic, i have answered in here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250957/installing-ios-apps-from-a-local-plist-null-would-like-to-install/13411918#13411918