# Installing iOS Apps from a local plist (null) would like to install

Tags: ios, null, ipa, adhoc

I'm trying to install an iOS app from a plist on the device's filesystem.

```
NSString *launchNewPlistURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=file://%@",[self saveFilePath]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:launchNewPlistURL]];
```

And I'm prompted with "(null) would like to install {myappname}". Usually (null) is the domain name the plist is coming from, but in this case it's null as it's a local file.

Is there anyway to specify the title in the plist or pass a fake domain name in the url?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 3):

You can use the project [MongooseDaemon](https://github.com/face/MongooseDaemon) to create an HTTP local server.

With a domain similar to: http://192.168.xxx.xxx/yourplist.plist to install it.

Anyhow, I think you can't use it with an large IPA. I have tried with my IPA greater than 15MB and it is very, very slow to start the install.

Comment: The file size shouldn't be a huge issue, as only the plist would need to be hosted by the MongooseDaemon, and the IPA could still live elsewhere on the web.

Answer (score 2):

I was in a similar situation, and went through the route of using Mongoose originally, but just today stumbled upon [CocoaHttpServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer).

With Mongoose, I was only getting about a 20% success rate serving up local plist/IPA files. Sometimes the `localhost would like to install` dialog never came up, sometimes install started and failed about halfway in, and sometimes it actually worked.  Even worse, once an App failed, I had to completely uninstall and reinstall it, so all data was lost. I was never able to successfully "fix" a failed install.

So far, with just about 10-15 minutes of testing, the CocoaHttpServer hasn't failed, yet. I know this is a very small sample size, but my Mongoose success rate was around 10%.

```
self.httpServer = [[HTTPServer alloc] init];
[self.httpServer setType:@"_http._tcp."];
[self.httpServer setPort:8080];
//This is just a path where I save my IPA and Plist file locally.  
//In my case it's /{NSDocumentDirectory}/install/
[self.httpServer setDocumentRoot:[self pathForLocalInstallFiles]];
```

Then the URL to the plist on the disk:

```
NSURL *plistUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://localhost:8080/appname.plist"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:plistUrl];
```

Inside the plist, where you have your URL that points to the local IPA file, I had success using either `file://` or `http://localhost/`.